# Select all rows 7 days prior from a specific date

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I want to get all rows 7 days prior from 01/09/2017

I know I can do

`Load_DTM <= '2017-01-09' and Load_DTM >= '2017-01-02'`

But can I not use DateAdd or DatePart?
i.e. `DateAdd(dd, -7, '2017-01-09')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load_DTM BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-7,'2017-01-09') AND '2017-01-09 11:59:59' 
ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do exactly what you showed in your example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateField = DATEADD(DAY, -7, '2017-09-01')
```

Since running:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Gives you:

2017-03-15 19:26:29.833